# Spring MVC: Login and logout functions?

Tags: java, xml, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am a complete newbie to Spring MVC and need help with login/logout functions. I have the login part figured out (I think), but am still struggling with the logout function. Do I need to establish a session in order to log the user out?

Controller Java file

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Login.do")
public String Login(@ModelAttribute("searchVO") UserInfoVO searchVO, ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

    int check = sampleService.loginSample(searchVO);

    String username = request.getParameter("registerUsername");
    String password = request.getParameter("registerPassword");

    if(check>0&&searchVO.getRegisterUsername()!=null){
        return "forward:/Menu.do";
    }

    else{
        return "sample/Login";
    }
}
```

---

Login XML File

```
<select id="leagueDAO.loginSample" parameterClass="userinfoVO" resultClass="int">

        SELECT COUNT(*) totcnt
        FROM REGISTER
        WHERE 1=1   
        AND REGISTERUSERNAME =  #registerUsername# 
        AND REGISTERPASSWORD = #registerPassword#

</select>
```

---

Login JSP Page

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c"      uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form"   uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="ui"     uri="http://egovframework.gov/ctl/ui"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value='/css/egovframework/sample.css'/>"/>

    <script type="text/javaScript" language="javascript" defer="defer">

    function doLogin(){
            document.listForm.action = "<c:url value='/Login.do?'/>";
        }

    function doRegisterPage(){
        document.listForm.action = "<c:url value='/Register.do?'/>";

        }

    </script>

</head>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
    <body style="font-family:Arial; text-align: center; font-size:16px; margin-left:330px;">
        <form:form commandName="loginForm" id="listForm" name="listForm" method="post">
                <h1 style="padding-top: 40px; margin-bottom:-10px; width:280px; height:300px; text-align:center; font-family:Mistral; font-size:56px; color:#000000; margin-top: 50px; margin-left:330px;">Welcome!

                <br/>
                <input id="registerUsername" onKeydown="Javascript: if (event.keyCode==13) javascript:doLogin();" align="middle" name="registerUsername" style="border: 5px padding: 8px 0px 0px 2px; margin-top:10px; width:200px; height:30px; font-family:Arial; font-size:18px;" type="text"></input>
                <input id="registerPassword" onKeydown="Javascript: if (event.keyCode==13) javascript:doLogin();" align="middle" name="registerPassword" style="border: 5px padding: 8px 0px 0px 2px; margin-top:10px; width:200px; height:30px; font-family:Arial; font-size:18px;" type="password"><br/></input>

                <button onclick="javascript:doLogin()" style="cursor:pointer; margin-top:20px; width:208px; height:40px; font-family:Arial; font-size: 16px; color: #FFFFFF; background-color: #32CD32;">Sign In</button><br/>
                <br/>
                <button onclick="javascript:doRegisterPage()" style="cursor:pointer; margin-bottom:30px;width:208px; height:40px; font-family:Arial; font-size: 16px; color: #FFFFFF; background-color: #0000CD;">Create Account</button><br/>
        </form:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

EDIT:

Error message when I add

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.invalidate();
```

---

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet action threw exception
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using Spring MVC, and it appears that you are trying to implement your own login and logout functionality. Instead, I would suggest using Spring Security to take care of authentication.

In pom.xml, add these in the dependencies section

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

And then, you can easily configure authentication using hard-coded users (`auth.inMemoryAuthentication()`), database (`auth.jdbcAuthentication()`), and other methods such as LDAP.

Creating your own authentication functionality poses great security risks, and I find it counterproductive since you're basically trying to reinvent the wheel. For academic or learning purposes especially in information security, sure it would be a good exercise. But if you're goal is to have good understanding of Spring as a whole, then learn Spring-Security as well.

Comment: How do I do the authentication thing? Sorry, I'm a complete newbie to programming.

Comment: Not using spring boot, but I am using Maven.

Comment: What you need to do is set maven dependencies, create configuration for spring security (either in dispatcher-servlet.xml or other xml configured in your listener), decide on your user authentication method (in memory, jdbc, ldap, etc), and create your login.html or login.jsp, then tie them all up together in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to login method, You can create a method in controller to get the session and invalidate it. Call this method when user clicks on logout.
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.invalidate();

Comment: I'm getting this error message:

org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke /
Servlet.service() for servlet action threw exception /
java.lang.StackOverflowError

Comment: Provide entire stacktrace and the code which is causing this error.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are not creating any session on login. You're simply redirecting the page.
Ref this to create a login and logout: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/html/jc.html